# Search in subfolder but exclude the folder above

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create for loop and to search specific directories for file type. My structure is as below:

```
tree -d -L 2 .
.
├── modules  <-- This folder don't have any configuration files and need to be skipped
│   └── lambda  <-- This folder is where I want to search for files 
├── sub1
│   └── lambda
├── sub10
├── sub1@tmp
├── sub2
│   └── lambda
├── sub3
│   └── lambda
├── sub7
│   └── lambda
└── sub9
    └── lambda
```

What the loop is doing is to search into the folders for specific file type and run command. Everything works as expected but the folder "modules" should be skipped from the loop and the folder inside "./modules/lambda" to be checked.

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
for d in $(find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3  -not -path "*/.*" -type f -name "*.tf" | awk -F / ' { print $2 } ')
  do
         cd ${d}
         echo `terraform init  && terraform apply --auto-approve`
         cd -
     done
```

If I run the command I see the below output, where I don't want to loop the modules folder but I want to loop throw the subfolders inside ex. lambda:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3  -not -path "*/.*" -type f -name "*.tf" | awk -F / ' { print $2 } '
sub1
modules
modules
sub2
sub3
sub7
sub9
```

Comment: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop on terraform file. Ok.

But:

- Don't loop directly on `find` output (special characters are not protected)
- Don't get directory name with `awk` (because you don't known the depth)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

while IFS= read -r -d '' tf_filename; do
  tf_dirname="${tf_filename%/*}"
  printf "Terraform dir = '%s'" "$tf_dirname"
  cd "${tf_dirname}" >/dev/null \
  && {
    terraform init && terraform apply --auto-approve
    cd - >/dev/null
  }
done < <(find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3  -not -path "*/.*" -type f -name "*.tf" -print0)
```

1. Loop on file (nul char separate your filenames, not space nor LF, CR, TAB... with `-print0` option)
2. Get directory name from filename
3. Condition your `terraform` execution with `cd` works

A version without '<(...)' operator:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3  -not -path "*/.*" -type f -name "*.tf" -print0 \
| while IFS= read -r -d '' tf_filename; do
  tf_dirname="${tf_filename%/*}"
  printf "Terraform dir = '%s'" "$tf_dirname"
  cd "${tf_dirname}" >/dev/null \
  && {
    terraform init && terraform apply --auto-approve
    cd - >/dev/null
  }
done
```

You also use this shebang: `#! /usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: Thanks for the advices, Arnaud. :)  

It seems in my case Jenkins controller don't want to read properly this script probably because Jenkins interpreter is "/bin/sh" and this is "/bin/bash" but even adding the sheband to the first is the same: 

+ set -xe
script.sh: 11: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Regards,
Ivo

Comment: I have added a version without `<(...)` operator. You also use `#! /usr/bin/env bash` shebang

Comment: Hi Arnaud, I appreciate your time and help to share with me and this version of the script but unfortunately I still have errors: 

script.sh: 5: read: Illegal option -d

Regards,
Ivo

Comment: Do you have a old  bash version (`bash --version`) ?

Comment: I don't think so. My current version is GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) and I'm running the script on docker container with Jenkins controller.

Comment: You need to execute this script with bash shell to use the builtin `read` command. There is no problem to use `<(...)` operator and `read -d` option with your bash version

Comment: Thanks. I had to switch the interpreter from /bin/sh to /bin/bash from the global configuration settings in Jenkins for the script to work and now everything seems fine. :)

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. Is there a way this script to check /modules/**/ subfolders and execute just the first command "terraform init". This folder is special and the content inside holds only templates for Terraform (configuration files). This configurations have variables and this variables don't have default values, so when the loop checks the folder and run the commands it will wait for some input values to continue. Below you can see example from the output:

 Enter a value: var.lambda_handler
 Lambda function handler
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE